# Console application auto start at boot with output to screen

Tags: c, linux, raspbian

I have my "c" application for raspbian which uses a lot of `printf` and `sprintf` to display the necessary information. 
The application should start automatically on boot and display the data on the screen without anyone beeing logged.
I had this running on older raspbian be adding this command in the file `/etc/rc.local`:

```
exec /path/application
```

Everything was fine until i installed it on latest raspbian (8, Jessie). 
Now the application starts from the `rc.local` but the only thing I get on the screen is "A start Job is running on rc.local".

So the application works fine but I don't see the necessary output on the screen which I had before.

I tried to run the application as a process from

```
/etc/rc2.d/S03application
```

but even if it successfully run there is no output on the screen :(

Is there any way to make the `rc.local` work as before? Or maybe redirecting the output from process to screen?

Please help